# Canvas interactive drawing with Javascript implemented on elementor

Tags: javascript, wordpress, canvas, html5-canvas, elementor

I wanted to implement an interactive drawing on my wordpress using the HTML element.
The code works well outside of wordpress but once implemented, the mouse movement seems off ( it is far away from the cursor). Any idea why that is ?
Here is the page where i want to implement the canva on wordpress : https://www.designme-asheep.com/

Here is the code :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Drawing app</title>
    <style>
        *,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
}

.container{
    margin-left: 2em;
}
.drawing-board{
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
}

#toolbar{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

input[type="color"]{

    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch{
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: none;
}

#lineWidth{
    visibility: hidden;
}

#clear{

    font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 4em;
    background-color: black;
    border: solid black 2px;
    padding-left:2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
    color: white;

}

#clear:hover{
    color: black;
    background-color: transparent;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="container">
        <div class="drawing-board">
            <canvas id="drawing-board"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div id="toolbar">
            <label for="stroke">Choisissez votre couleur : </label>
            <input id="stroke" name='stroke' type="color" value="#43da86">
            <button id="clear">Effacer</button>
            <input id="lineWidth" name='lineWidth' type="number" value="18">
        </div>
    </section>

<script>
    const canvas = document.getElementById('drawing-board');
const toolbar = document.getElementById('toolbar');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const canvasOffsetX = canvas.offsetLeft;
const canvasOffsetY = canvas.offsetTop;

canvas.width = window.innerWidth - canvasOffsetX;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight - canvasOffsetY;

let isPainting = false;
let lineWidth = 18;
let startX;
let startY;

toolbar.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.id === 'clear') {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
});

toolbar.addEventListener('change', e => {
    if(e.target.id === 'stroke') {
        ctx.strokeStyle = e.target.value;
    }

    if(e.target.id === 'lineWidth') {
        lineWidth = e.target.value;
    }
    
});

const draw = (e) => {
    if(!isPainting) {
        return;
    }

    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';

    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX - canvasOffsetX, e.clientY);
    ctx.stroke();
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    isPainting = true;
    startX = e.clientX;
    startY = e.clientY;
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
    isPainting = false;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried changing the Canvas size and removing any margin.

Comment: Could be that the position of the canvas changes after you saved `canvasOffsetX` and `Y`. I would suggest you always update those on mousedown. Also, don't forget to actually use `canvasOffsetY` in `lineTo`.

Comment: You might want to show what is going on by adding an image to your question